# Custom Mapping entire Array

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to apply a custom mapping using Knockout. I've got a JSON object that contains this JSON fragment:

```
{
    "feature": { "id": "BEAM_TYPE2" },
    "label": { "ux_value": "BEAM_TYPE", "tooltipText": "" },
    "help": { "ux_title": "BEAM_TYPE_HELP", "ux_value": "BEAM_TYPE_DESCRIPTION" },
    "control": { 
         "type": "dropdown", 
         "options": [
             { "ux_value": "BEAM_TYPE_BOX", "value": "BOX" }, 
             { "ux_value": "BEAM_TYPE_IBEAM", "value": "IBEAM" }, 
             { "ux_value": "BEAM_TYPE_PFC", "value": "PFC" }, 
             { "ux_value": "BEAM_TYPE_OPEN", "value": "OPEN" }, 
             { "ux_value": "BEAM_TYPE_ZTYPE", "value": "ZTYPE" }, 
             { "ux_value": "BEAM_TYPE_BOX_ANGLE", "value": "BOX_ANGLE" }, 
             { "ux_value": "BEAM_TYPE_STEP", "value": "STEP" }
         ], 
         "value": "BOX" 
    }
}
```

Ultimately the `options` get converted to an observable array and bound to a dropdown. However I've now decided that I actually want to vary the values within this array dynamically, and instead provide a computed function, so a dummy hardcoded example:

```
ko.computed(function() {
    return [
       { ux_value: "A", value: "A" },
       { ux_value: "B", value: "B" },
       { ux_value: "C", value: "C" }
    ];
});
```

I decided using the custom binding in `ko.mapping` would be the best way to do this, so I tried using the creation function:

```
var mapping = {
        'options': {
            create: function (options) {
                debugger;
            }
        }
    };
```

Unfortunately what I've found is that I hit the breakpoint for every single item within the array, so in the example shown I'd hit my breakpoint 7 times, whereas I only want to hit it once and return the resultant object. Would the correct way of handling this to work on the `control` instead of the `options` and manually creating the bindings for all the other values or is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: how and when will the options objects change dynamically?

Comment: @NathanFisher the computed values could change at any point after being bound. Essentially a rule will be added where other observables will change the available options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try moving one level up and create a mapping function for the control property instead.

```
var mapping = {
        'control': {
            create: function (control) {
                debugger;
            }
        }
    };
```

And create add the computed functions to that.

Comment: Yeah - I did note that as a possibility in my question, but valid answer. I guess I was trying to avoid having to do that, as then I need to take care of all the other properties manually.